# Organizing two kinds of navigation in a mobile app

Tags: mobile, navigation, mobile-application, tab-bar

**The problem:**

There are usually 3-4 tabs on a mobile navigation menu, as shown below. This is considered to be best practice. However, we have 5-6 features we would like to display there.

[image]

We are trying to design the navigation so we can abide by a simple tab-based format like the one shown above, so we tried to figure out how to organize these major features.

**How we're trying to solve the problem:**

We decided to use a toggle at the top that switches between "Feature Set 1" and "Feature Set 2." Move the toggle only shows 3 of the features in the tab bar below at a time.

This feels odd and clunky. What is best practice in solving this problem?

Comment: You do need to explain more. Maybe add in some screenshots and better define the scope.

Comment: @CristianNegraia Thanks for the feedback. Added more info above.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your questions correctly you would like to add more navigation menu items, on the bottom navigation bar in your app, than is possible (visual).

What we did in a concept was:
- Show 4 (most used) items in the bottom navigation bar
- The fifth item was a hamburger or submenu (the 3 dots) with the title 'More' on the most right side of the bottom navigation bar.

We designed the app so that we could track the most used menu items and update the app with the 4 first items being the ones that are most used.

Almost all users found the navigation in this way more usefull then a standard hamburger (for webportal om mobile)

Answer (score 0):

you are adding an extra step in order to allow the user to view more menu items. if your menu items can be differentiated and grouped, i guess you could use another design element to trigger menu 2, but why not make that bottom menu scrollable horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

Your Tabs Bar look like all iPhone apps did in the past (Without judging). Meanwhile, however, more and more deviate from that approach. Best example: Facebook.

The following screenshot was taken right now.

[image: facebook app]

The tab bar works pretty good and it also looks appealing. And it has exactly 6 items, so maybe this will work for you, too.

You can assume that experienced users can handle it and the other, inexperienced ones use Facebook anyway, so they are familiar with this design pattern.

But please: Still use text labels below the icons.